# Measurability of the zero-crossing time of Brownian motion

Tags: measure-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I have the following random time $\tau = \inf\{t > 0: W_t = 0\}$ where $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is Brownian motion with almost surely continuous paths and $W_0 = 0$ a.s. I need to prove that $\tau$ is measurable (not necessarily a stopping time or an optional time). I first fix $\omega \in \Omega' \subset \Omega$. On $\Omega'$ $W$ is continuous and null at $0$. Then, I claim

$$\tau_0(\omega) > s \Leftrightarrow \lvert W_t(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{t}, 0 < t \leq s$$
By continuity of $t \mapsto W_t(\omega)$,
\begin{equation}\lvert W_t(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{t}, 0 < t \leq s \Leftrightarrow \lvert W_{q_t}(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{q_t} \in Q_s \qquad (\triangle)\end{equation}
where $Q_s = \{qs \vert q \in (0,1] \cap Q\}$. Then 
$$\{\tau_0(\omega) > s\} = \underbrace{\cap_{q_t \in Q_s} \underbrace{\{\lvert W_{q_t} \rvert > 0\}}_{\in \mathcal{F}}}_{\in \mathcal{F}, \text{ by countable intersection}}$$

Now I don't think this is correct. In particular, $(\triangle)$ seems wrong. Take $s = 1$ for example. Then consider the function $t \mapsto -t/r + 1$ where $r \in [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Can someone help me fix this proof?

Comment: A gap in your argument: A continuous path can hit zero without changing sign.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you. I missed that. How would I characterize the set where BM touches zero and bounces back in "measurable" terms? Oh wait, I just add a third rational time point where BM is 0, right?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Sorry about the last sentence in my previous comment. BM does not have to touch zero at a rational time point of course. But then I still don't know how to formulate that set.

Comment: **Hints:** Let $C$ be the event $\{\omega: W_0(\omega)=0$, $t\mapsto W_t(\omega)$ is continuous$\}$. It is your hypothesis that $\Bbb P[C]=1$. The event $A:=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{q\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,1/n)}\{\omega: W_q(\omega)>0\}$ is measurable, and $\Bbb P[A]=1$.
Likewise, $B:=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{q\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,1/n)}\{\omega: W_q(\omega)<0\}$ is measurable, and $\Bbb P[B]=1$.
Finally, $A\cap B\cap C\subset \{\omega:\tau(\omega)=0\}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks for the hint. Based on that I made a modification to my claim. Could you take a look at it please, if it won't be too much trouble for you?

Comment: Just as a side remark: More generally, $$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0;W_t \in F\}$$ is measurable for any closed set $F$ (in fact, it is a stopping time wrt natural filtration).

Comment: Dear @saz, thank you as always for your help. My case is slightly different in that $t = 0$ is not included in the infimum. Later on I will have to show that $\tau = 0$ a.s.

Comment: @Calculon Ah, I see, I missed this detail. However, the statement in my previous comment remains valid if you replace "$t \geq 0$" by "$t>0$". Regarding your claim: No, that's not correct. First of all, $t$ is fixed so why is there a "$\exists s,t$" at the right-hand side?(I guess that's a "different" $t$) ... and anyway, this looks still rather overcomplicated to me. Why do you need two sequences ....?

Comment: @saz I ran out of symbols. That is indeed a different $t$. I forgot that I had used it. 

I wanted two sequences so that the sequence approaching $t$ the from the left would not converge to $t$. My intention was make sure that the zero-crossing time is strictly between $0$ and $t$.

Comment: @Calculon You can avoid this by considering the event $\{\tau \leq t\}$; then it doesn't matter whether the sequence (from the left) converges to $t$.

Comment: @saz Thank you. I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: @saz I tried to simplify my answer but this time I couldn't convince myself that what I am doing is right. Do you know a simple, elegant solution to this? By the way $\tau$ as defined in my question is not a stopping time because there is an accumulation of zero crossings at time $0$.

Comment: "By the way $\tau$ as defined in my question is not a stopping time because there is an accumulation of zero crossings at time $0$." ?? Note that being a stopping time is a matter of measurability; e.g. also the trivial randomv variable $\tau := 0$ is a stopping time.

Comment: @saz Yes but it is measurability in a very particular form, i.e. $\{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$. I will post the proof if I can find it but $\tau$ in my question does not satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the following elementary statement:

> Let $f: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then $f(t)=0$ for some $t \in [0,T]$ if, and only if, $$\inf_{q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,T]} |f(q)| = 0.$$

Applying this lemma, we find that

$$\{\tau \leq T\} = \{\omega; \exists t \in [0,T]: W_t(\omega)=0\} = \left\{\omega; \inf_{q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,T]} |W_q(\omega)| = 0\right\}$$

Because $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,T]$ is countable and each $W_q$ is measurable, we know that

$$\omega \mapsto \inf_{q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,T]} |W_q(\omega)| $$

is measurable and this implies that $\{\tau \leq T\}$ is measurable for each $T$. Consequently, $\tau$ is measurable.

**Remark:** This reasoning works, more generally, if $\tau$ is of the form $$\tau := \inf\{t >0; W_t \in F\}$$ for some closed set $F$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That elementary statement is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Calculon You are welcome.