# Last exit time of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to show that the last exit time of Brownian motion is a random variable, i.e. for $\tau$ defined as

$$\tau = \sup\{t > 0 : W_t = 0\}$$
it holds that $\{\tau < t\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for every $t > 0$. Here $W$ is BM on the filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}((\mathcal{F}_t))_t,P)$.

Here is my attempt:
Fix $\omega \in \Omega'$. On $\Omega'$ BM is continuous and null at $0$. $\Omega'$ is measurable.
$$\tau(\omega) < t \Leftrightarrow \lvert W_s(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{s} \geq t$$

$$\lvert W_s(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{s} \geq t \Leftrightarrow \forall{n} \in \mathbb{Z}_{>t}, \lvert W_s(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{s}, t\leq s \leq n$$

Now fix $n$. By continuity of BM,
$$\lvert W_s(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{s}, t\leq s \leq n \Leftrightarrow 
\lvert W_{q^n_s}(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{q^n_s} \in Q_n$$
where $Q_n = \{q(n-t)+t \vert q \in [0,1]\cap Q\}$

Something is wrong with the last step. BM can just bounce back at an irrational time point but I cannot fix it without using limits. I had a similar problem with the second hitting time at $0$ ([Measurability of the zero-crossing time of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693570/measurability-of-the-zero-crossing-time-of-brownian-motion)). Is there a clever solution to this?

If I am not missing a point, hopefully this solves the problem in the last step.

$$\lvert W_s(\omega) \rvert > 0 \quad \forall{s}, t\leq s \leq n \Leftrightarrow 
\exists{q\in\mathbb{Q}}, q> 0, \lvert W_{q^n_s}(\omega) \rvert > q \quad \forall{q^n_s} \in Q_n$$
where $Q_n = \{q(n-t)+t \vert q \in [0,1]\cap Q\}$

Comment: Hint: $$[\tau\geqslant t]=\bigcup_{n\geqslant0}\bigcap_{k\geqslant1}\bigcup_{t\leqslant q\leqslant t+n,\,q\in\mathbb Q}[|W_q|\leqslant 1/k]$$

Comment: Isn't $\tau$ almost surely infinite anyway?

Comment: @carmichael561 It is. but before you can give probabilities to events regarding $\tau$ you need to show that it is actually a random variable.

Comment: @carmichael561 Indeed, but the measurability issue applies to other continuous random processes as well.

Comment: @ Did: fair enough. @Calculon: if your filtration contains the $\mathbb{P}$-null sets (which is a common assumption), then any almost-surely constant random variable will automatically be measurable.

Comment: @carmichael561 We haven't imposed the usual conditions in this exercise. But thank you for the remark!

Comment: @Did Thank you for the hint. I understand it but I also would like to make my way work. I updated my answer. Could you please comment on that if you have time?